# Errors using reverse geocoding on Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, geolocation, reverse-geocoding

I'm working on a university assignment right now where I need to create a windows phone 8 app to display the users current location as coordinates and in plaintext address format.

I got it working fine for the coordinates using the Geolocator class where when the user clicked a button their coordinates were displayed.

Now, i've moved on to trying to return the address from the coordinates using the Reverse geocoding class but can't get it to work.

My full code is as follows

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
using PhoneApp1.Resources;
using Windows.Devices.Geolocation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Services;
using System.Text;


namespace PhoneApp1
{
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Sample code to localize the ApplicationBar
        //BuildLocalizedApplicationBar();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        GetCurrentLocation();
    }


    private async void GetCurrentLocation()
    {
        Geolocator locationFinder = new Geolocator
        {
            DesiredAccuracyInMeters = 50,
            DesiredAccuracy = PositionAccuracy.Default
        };
        try
        {
            Geoposition currentLocation = await locationFinder.GetGeopositionAsync(
            maximumAge: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120),
            timeout: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            String longitude = currentLocation.Coordinate.Longitude.ToString("0.00");
            String latitude = currentLocation.Coordinate.Latitude.ToString("0.00");
            MyTextBlock.Text = "Long: " + longitude + " Lat: " + latitude;

        }

  catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
  {
      MessageBox.Show("And Exception Occured");
  }
    }

 public ReverseGeocodeQuery(double longitude, double latitude) {
    MapAddress address;

    ReverseGeocodeQuery query = new ReverseGeocodeQuery();
    query.GeoCoordinate = currentLocation;
    query.QueryCompleted += (s, e) =>
    {
    if (e.Error != null)
        return;

    address = e.Result[0].Information.Address;
};
query.QueryAsync();  
 }

 }

  }
  }
```

The two errors I'm getting when I run the program are

Error   1   Method must have a return type  U:\visual studio 2012\Projects\PhoneApp1\PhoneApp1\MainPage.xaml.cs 59  13  PhoneApp1

Error   2   The type 'Windows.Devices.Geolocation.Geocoordinate' has no constructors defined    U:\visual studio 2012\Projects\PhoneApp1\PhoneApp1\MainPage.xaml.cs 63  31  PhoneApp1

Any input is appreciated, hopefully one of you can help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have  errors of compilation which are showed there.

You must specified return type in your method like this

```
public void ReverseGeocodeQuery(double longitude, double latitude) {
MapAddress address;

ReverseGeocodeQuery reverseQuery = new ReverseGeocodeQuery { 
GeoCoordinate = currentLocation.coordinate };
query.QueryCompleted += (s, e) =>
{
if (e.Error != null)
    return;

address = e.Result[0].Information.Address;
};
query.QueryAsync();  
}

}
```

Another one error is you can then get the GeoCoordinate instance from Geoposition in your method that get the currentlocation.